# How to navigate multiples pages in NativeScript app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, nativescript

I am a web designer coming from Cordova for mobile apps dev. I read and watch many tutorials for NativeScript for beginners and I am in love with it but none of those tutorials teach me how to navigate an app with hidden content (pages/sections).

I mean something like a list of news and when click on an item the app reveal with a transition a new screen with the full content of the post.

May you help me to get any kind of tutorial or info to deal with what I need? Thanks for any help, I will appreciate it.

NativeScript is a beauty but look like isn't popular like React/React-Native is (I hate React). :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As prior answers mention, Nativescript offers you the possibility to add Angular support. This enables a convenient navigation with the `@angular/router`.
Follow the [official docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation) on how to set this up.

If you want to avoid the Angular overhead, you can just use the `frameModule` like described [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-3#32-navigating-screens).

Best regards, 
David

Comment: Look like frameModule is what I need. Thanks for your help. :-D

Comment: Glad I could help you. Have fun playing/working with nativescript!

Answer (score 1):

welcome to community NS, You could tell me if using NS white vainilla, core or Angular, if using Angular you can see this tutorial.

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/10/navigating-nativescript-app-angular-2-router/

Comment: I prefer vanilla NS. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this would let me know check the link
https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/06/05/nativescript-showing-and-hiding-elements/